# Detectar tipo de campo enviado no POST PHP

Tags: php, html, input, custom-post-types

Existe como identificar o tipo de campo que está vindo num post?

Se é Text ou Array?

Exemplo:

Tenho listbox (select multiple) e campos text no html, e nele o usuário pode ou não selecionar valores, tenho uma função onde verifico os valores dos campos antes de prosseguir, mas quando tenho esse tipo de campo no meio me da problema, eu precisava tratar de um forma diferente quando ele vem no post.

Comment: Você pode utilizar `is_array($_POST["nome_do_campo"]);`. Retornando `true`, é um *array*.

Answer (score 1):

Existe a função `gettype()` que retorna uma string que identifica o tipo de dado que é a variável passada para o parâmetro, inclusive se ela é um array. Pode usar isso para tratar seu código.

Por exemplo, um `gettype([1,2]);` retornaria `'array'`, `gettype(1);` retornaria `'integer'`, `gettype('teste');` retornaria `'string'` e assim por diante. Sendo também posível fazer isso para valores vindos via post, como `gettype($_POST['campo']);`.

Mais na documentação oficial >>http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.gettype.php